# Will the feasible region always be convex in linear programming?

Tags: linear-programming

In linear programming we find a feasible region , is this region always convex? . if a concave region is found where objective is minimization , I think then a solution exists .
Advance thanks.

someone deleted the answer of my previous post , although i wasn't sure about the answer of 1st question , and no one is replying in that post , as i am in hurry so i re-posted it to get a  answer. Thanks

Comment: Why do you ask this again? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/437979/in-linear-programming-will-the-feasible-region-always-be-convex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because the constraints in a linear program are linear, they will always produce a convex body.  With finitely many constraints, it will in fact be a [convex polytope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_polytope).  If you want a feasible region to be concave (or any other shape for that matter), you'll have to look to nonlinear constraint functions.